# How do you properly impliment d3.svg.diagonal() in D3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking for how to properly implement the replacement for the diagonal function in d3 v4.9 and greater using link shapes.

In d3 v3, I was using:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();
```

But now `.diagonal()` is undefined.

Comment: FWIW, the accepted answer in the original question is outdated.